# Count for a word in Kafka KTable starts with some random value, in context of wordcount application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

In Kafka Streams Wordcount application, I am grouping the incoming records by key and storing the count in the Materialized KTable :

```
public void process(@Input(Binding.INPUT) KStream<String, String> stream) {
   stream
            .peek((k, v) -> {
                System.out.println("INCOMING :: KEY = " + k + " , VALUE = " + v);
            })
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v, v))
            .groupByKey()
            .count(Materialized.as(Binding.STORENAME));
}
```

I am using InteractiveQueryService to read from the Kafka store :

```
@Component
public class CountQueryProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;

    private ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Long> readOnlyKeyValueStore;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 0, fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void queryStore() {
        readOnlyKeyValueStore = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(Binding.STORENAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

        KeyValueIterator<String, Long> iterator = readOnlyKeyValueStore.all();
        while(iterator.hasNext())   {
            KeyValue<String, Long> next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Query :: Word = " + next.key + " , Count = " + next.value);
        }
    }
}
```

When the values from the KTable Store is printed, its starts with random value and start incrementing.
I do not understand why it happens.

Any solution to fix this and explanation behind the scenes would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add the output you observe to the question, ie, what do you mean by "random value"? Do you mean that the count does not start at one?

Comment: Yes @Matthias, the count does not start at 1

Comment: Could it be, that is finds old local state? Try to change the `application.id` to verify if this might fix the issue?